# ActiveX List Boxes will not "Size and Move" with their parent cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new at VBA so sorry in advance if this is a silly question. I have a Worksheet with ActiveX List boxes. The worksheet also has Toggle Switches. The toggle switches are set up to Hide Rows and ActiveX boxes when not depressed and  Show Rows and ActiveX boxes when depressed. I'd like to save the file with all of the Toggle switches not depressed so that the user can un-hide only the rows and boxes that they need. Everything works properly until I save the file with all rows hidden. After the save all of the boxes change locations. I've tried setting the boxes to "Move and Size with cell", "Move but don't size with cell", and "Don't more or Size with cell" in the preferences. The same thing happens with all options. Below is my toggle switch code. Is there something in there causing this to happen?

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
 If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
         'This area contains the things you want to happen
         'when the toggle button is not depressed
        Range("101:183").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheet1.Range("94:144").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          'This hides the listboxes since they can not move and
          'size with cells
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox2").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox3").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox4").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox5").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox6").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox7").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox8").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox9").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox10").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox11").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox12").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox13").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox14").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox15").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox16").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox17").Visible = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox18").Visible = True

    Else
         'This area contains the things you want to happen
         'when the toggle button is depressed
        Range("101:183").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheet1.Range("94:144").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox2").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox3").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox4").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox5").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox6").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox7").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox8").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox9").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox10").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox11").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox12").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox13").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox14").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox15").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox16").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox17").Visible = False
        Sheet11.OLEObjects("ListBox18").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When I set the listbox properties to "Don't more or Size with cell" and I hide the first 10,000 rows of the sheet save the file, close and reopen the listboxes stay where i place them, I am sorry but I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: It works for me when I save and don't exit the the file. When I exit and re-enter is when the boxes have moved. All of the boxes will be piled up on the top row in the array that I'm hiding.

Comment: I don't know if this would solve your issue, but when re-sizing the controls if you hold the **Alt** key this will make them fit the cell boundaries. I suspect an issue can occur if they overlap to another row and/or column.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is it by accident you forgot to save the file with the property "Don't more or Size with cell" selected? by accident? or you didn't set the property on all of the boxes?

Comment: I would also turn off the screen-updating, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, before all these UI changes.

Comment: @Andy G "I don't know if this would solve your issue, but when re-sizing the controls if you hold the Alt key this will make them fit the cell boundaries. I suspect an issue can occur if they overlap to another row and/or column. – " I thought of this too. I've tried making the rows & Columns larger so the boxes fit in and I've tried merging cell. Both ways the boxes behave the same way. If I can figure out how to post a copy of the worksheet I will.

Comment: As part of a debugging process I would copy the workbook and delete all but two of the listboxes. This would help to focus on, and hopefully, discover the issue. Perhaps the listboxes themselves overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the answer to your question (I haven't even looked at it yet), but i just felt like giving you this code, this is the exact code you provided and will function the same way, just looks a tiny bit clearer (actually as it also removes the if statement it prolly even performs at like 1/1000000 of a millisecond faster also =D)

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Dim boolToggleValue As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    boolToggleValue = ToggleButton1.Value
    'This area contains the things you want to happen
    'when the toggle button is not depressed
    Range("101:183").EntireRow.Hidden = Not boolToggleValue
    Sheet1.Range("94:144").EntireRow.Hidden = Not boolToggleValue
    'This hides the listboxes since they can not move and
    'size with cells
    With Sheet11
        For i = 1 To 18
            .OLEObjects("ListBox" & i).Visible = boolToggleValue
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a cleaner way and I tried something similar and it didn't work :/

Comment: I would also store the `ToggleButton1.Value` once, in a Boolean variable, rather than re-reading it 20 times.